# Out of gas on truffle test

Tags: contract-development, truffle

I am following the tutorial on http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

I am using Ganache for testing, where i am also deploying the tutorial contract.

```
  1) TestAdoption "before all" hook: prepare suite:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
```

What does this mean?
The tests are simple, the contract doesn't do much. 
Where is the gas limit set?

I started ganache with

```
ganache-cli -l 500000000
```

Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can set in your package json a script

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "truffle test --network _development"
},
```

and in `truffle-config.js` (windows) or `truffle.js` (mac/linux) the gas limit, every network has a gas limit you can query with Geth,

```
networks: {
        _development: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9545,
            network_id: 4447,
            gasPrice: 1,
            gas: 4700000
        },
```

to run your test: `npm run test` or `yarn run test`